# wordpress category with products on home page

Tags: wordpress

I want to display one category with products on home page. I'm using wp-ecommerce plugin. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the page you need: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

//The Query
query_posts('**cat=4**');

//The Loop
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 .. do stuff
endwhile; else:
 ..
endif;

//Reset Query
wp_reset_query();

?>